# given word as input not find out in text but still it return Word found as output instead of Word not found. So can you correct it?

Tags: python

```
# enter code here
text=input()
word=input()
def search(text ,word):
    if (text.find(word)):
        print('Word found')
    else:
        print('Word not found')

search(text, word)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` method returns the index from where a word is found otherwise -1.

which means if the word is not found, `text.find(word)` will return -1 and -1 is truthy value. Thus the condition for if statement becomes truthy always, thus always printing `word found`.

So, one way to get it right is to do this;

```
# enter code here
text=input()
word=input()
def search(text ,word):
    if (text.find(word) != -1): # only change here
        print('Word found')
    else:
        print('Word not found')

search(text, word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text=input()
word=input()
def search(text ,word):
   if (text in word):
       print('Word found')
   else:
      print('Word not found')

search(text, word)  

str.find(word)
```

If the substring exists inside the string, it returns the index of the first occurence of the substring.
If a substring doesn't exist inside the string, it returns -1.

```
if (text.find(word)):
       print('Word found')
   else:
      print('Word not found')  

input text='hii'
  word='hii'
output='Word not found'
```

find will return first occurence index that is 0 so condition will be false and else block will be executed